# Get Dockerfile that generated by pack build --builder gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-build

I tried pack builder feature from Google Cloud, it's working fine. I'm glad that there's such feature that make deploying app easily. I mean it handles automatically without writing `Dockerfile`, `cloudbuild.yaml`, or `app.yaml`. So, my project structure will be looks like this:

```
api-sukarinse/
├── config
│   └── database.js
├── controllers
│   ├── articles.js
│   ├── faq.js
│   ├── favorite.js
│   ├── laundry.js
│   ├── owner.js
│   ├── refreshToken.js
│   ├── review.js
│   ├── service.js
│   ├── transaction.js
│   ├── uploadImage.js
│   └── users.js
├── helper
│   ├── article.js
│   ├── imgUpload.js
│   └── utils.js
├── imgUpload.json
├── middleware
│   ├── folderMiddleware.js
│   └── verifyToken.js
├── models
│   ├── favoriteModel.js
│   ├── laundryModel.js
│   ├── ownerModel.js
│   ├── reviewModel.js
│   ├── serviceModel.js
│   ├── transactionModel.js
│   ├── transactionServiceModel.js
│   └── userModel.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── routes
│   └── index.js
└── ujang.js
```

As you see there's no `Dockerfile` at my project structure.

I also change non-standard best practice nodejs app main file with changing `index.js` (common naming) to `ujang.js` to just test it with following edit the `package.json`.

Surprisingly it can detect automatically what I expect after I deploy it to the **Cloud Run**.

The output given from `pack build` is **docker image**, therefore I feel a little blackbox to not knowing what happened inside it during building. That's make me wonder that lead me to ask this question. So, how do I get Dockerfile from pack builder?